# Using Cesium Unity in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine, cesiumjs

I'm trying to develop a 3D globe application by using Cesium's Unity version.

Since am a newbie at both Unity and Cesium, I could not figure it out how to implement it. Then I asked chat-gpt to how, in order to have an insight. The following piece of code had been provided by chat-gpt.

My question is, would it work? If so, how could I find the required packages or assemblies to import them into my project.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
    xmlns:cu="clr-namespace:Cesium.Unity.Wpf;assembly=Cesium.Unity.Wpf"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost>
        <wf:Panel x:Name="cesiumPanel" Dock="Fill">
            <cu:CesiumControl x:Name="cesiumControl" Dock="Fill" />
        </wf:Panel>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

C# Code:

```
using System.Windows;
using Cesium.Unity.Wpf;
using UnityEngine;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Initialize Cesium Unity
        CesiumInitializer.Initialize();

        // Configure Cesium Unity
        var cesiumViewer = cesiumControl.CesiumViewer;
        cesiumViewer.Camera.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1);
        cesiumViewer.Camera.Fov = 60;
        cesiumViewer.Camera.Near = 0.1;
        cesiumViewer.Camera.Far = 10000000;
        cesiumViewer.Scene.SkyBox.Show = false;
        cesiumViewer.Scene.Globe.Show = true;
        cesiumViewer.Scene.Globe.ImageryLayers.AddImageryProvider(new BingMapsImageryProvider
        {
            MapStyle = BingMapsStyle.AerialWithLabels
        });

        // Create a sample entity
        var entity = new Cesium.Entity
        {
            Position = new Cesium.Cartesian3(0, 0, 0),
            Ellipsoid = new Cesium.Ellipsoid(500000.0, 500000.0, 500000.0),
            Name = "Sample Entity",
            Show = true
        };

        // Add the entity to the scene
        cesiumViewer.Scene.Primitives.Add(new Cesium.Primitive
        {
            GeometryInstances =
            {
                new Cesium.GeometryInstance
                {
                    Geometry = new Cesium.EllipsoidGeometry
                    {
                        Radii = entity.Ellipsoid.Radii,
                        VertexFormat = Cesium.VertexFormat.PositionAndNormal
                    },
                    ModelMatrix = Cesium.Matrix4.Translation(entity.Position),
                    Attributes = new Cesium.GeometryAttributes
                    {
                        Normal = new Cesium.GeometryAttribute
                        {
                            ComponentDatatype = Cesium.ComponentDatatype.Float,
                            ComponentsPerAttribute = 3,
                            Values = new[]
                            {
                                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's Wpf adding to this? I think Cesium is a unity plugin and unity is mono based. I think if the whole focus of your app is not-wpf then you shouldn't use wpf

Comment: Hello Andy, 

We have an existing WPF application that contains GIS features and map control in it. However, the GIS library provider had closed and we no longer will be able to use it. Therefore I am trying to find another solution. Since we are planning to move web based application in future, we are trying to find a solution that we could easly migrate from WPF to web. From that point, we thought that Cesium-Unity could be a promising choice but we are not sure.

Comment: To be more clear about unity and cesium usage:
1. We would like to put a Control inside the WPF Window as given in the code sample above and initialize it on the c# part. 
2. We think that we don't need to use Unity Editor or any unity infrastructure since we are just trying to put a globe on that View. 
3. In the code part we are planning to add some methods to add some symbols or objects on that globe programmatically.

Maybe we could consider it like using Chromium WebControl on View and rendering the Index.html (cesium) just to provide scene. I hope this explains much more.